# Split a single raster into multiple rasters based on the attributes in R

Tags: raster, r, reclassify

I have a land cover raster which has 15 land cover classes (which previously had 70 land cover classes and I aggregated the same). However, I realized that I need 15 different rasters based on each of the land cover types. Is there any way I can achieve this in R?

```
lulc_2015 <- raster("E:\\LandCover_Data\\2015_lulc")

#Load matrix to be used for reclassification
rec <- read.csv("E:\\LandCover_ReclassifyMatrix.csv")

#Reclassifying the Raster to convert 70 LC to 15 LC
rc <- as.matrix(data.frame(from=rec$V2, to=rec$To))

New_LULC_2015 <- reclassify(lulc_2015,rc)

New_LULC_2015 <- ratify(New_LULC_2015)
rat <- data.frame(
  ID= 1:15,
  LandCover = c("Evergreen","Deciduous","Mixed Forest",
            "grass","Degraded Forest","Scrubland",
            "Dry Grassland","Wet Grassland","Plantation",
            "Settlement","High Elevation Plantation","Coastal",
            "Barren Land","Cropland","Wetlands")
  )

  levels(New_LULC_2015)<- rat

 > New_LULC_2015
 class       : RasterLayer 
 dimensions  : 642, 382, 245244  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
 extent      : 461951, 843951, 892583.3, 1534583  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 data source : in memory
 names       : layer 
 values      : 1, 15  (min, max)
 attributes  :
       ID LandCover
 from:  1 Evergreen
 to  : 15  Wetlands
```

If I try creating a new raster, I get this error.

```
> raster(New_LULC_2015@data@attributes[[1]]$ID==1)
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature 
 ‘"logical"’
```

I simply need 15 different rasters, for Evergreen, Deciduous etc. I need these as I realized I need to use the predict function from the raster package for a random forest model (Unless I don't really need to create separate rasters).

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Is it regarding the error (due to "agg_modal" being defined but not existing) or that you want to create 15 rasters representing each class? Please edit and clarify what you are after here. An easy way to tackle the reclassifying is: r.evergreen <- ew_LULC_2015; r.evergreen[r.evergreen != 15] <- 0  This will result in a raster with values of [0,15].

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have included the agg_modal. Let me edit it to clarify what I need to achieve here.

Comment: Your above suggestion is probably the best way to get around reclassifying. That definitely simplifies issues - r.evergreen <- ew_LULC_2015; r.evergreen[r.evergreen != 15] <- 0 .

Comment: You can use `mask()`, is faster: `r.evergreen <- mask(ew_LULC_2015, ew_LULC_2015[ew_LULC_2015 != 15], mask.value=0)`. Also, take a look of `assign()` to create different objects inside a loop

Comment: Do either of you want to post the solution? I can accept the answer.

Comment: Can you include an example for assign() as well @aldo_tapia ?

Comment: @VijayRamesh tomorrow I’ll post a solution with `assign()`, now I’m far from a machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mask()` to create rasters by each class and `assign()` to assign class names to new rasters. A reproducible example:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(123)

New_LULC_2015 <- raster()

values(New_LULC_2015) <- sample(x = 1:15,size = ncell(New_LULC_2015),replace = T)

rat <- data.frame(
  ID= 1:15,
  LandCover = c("Evergreen","Deciduous","Mixed Forest",
                "grass","Degraded Forest","Scrubland",
                "Dry Grassland","Wet Grassland","Plantation",
                "Settlement","High Elevation Plantation","Coastal",
                "Barren Land","Cropland","Wetlands")
)

levels(New_LULC_2015)<- rat

ls() # to see which objects are created in the workspace
## [1] "New_LULC_2015" "rat" 

# create class names without space
rat$class_names <- gsub(pattern = ' ' ,replacement = '_',x = rat$LandCover)
```

There are two frequent methods to achieve this (as was exposed in comments). I like to use `mask()` because is faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)

test <- New_LULC_2015

microbenchmark(method_A=test[test != 1] <-NA,
               metohd_B=mask(test,test!=1, maskvalue=1))

## Unit: milliseconds
##      expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
##  method_A 11.409580 11.743502 12.29027 12.136334 12.598599 17.27935   100   b
##  metohd_B  5.770045  6.502082  6.96712  6.612055  6.972143 11.85464   100  a 

remove(test)
```

Finally, create the new rasters based on the second method:

```
for(i in 1:15){
  assign(rat$class_names[i],mask(New_LULC_2015,New_LULC_2015 != i, maskvalue=1))
}

ls()
##  [1] "Barren_Land"               "Coastal"                   "Cropland"                 
##  [4] "Deciduous"                 "Degraded_Forest"           "Dry_Grassland"            
##  [7] "Evergreen"                 "grass"                     "High_Elevation_Plantation"
## [10] "i"                         "Mixed_Forest"              "New_LULC_2015"            
## [13] "Plantation"                "rat"                       "Scrubland"                
## [16] "Settlement"                "Wet_Grassland"             "Wetlands"
```

Also, you can drop items to a list if you don't want to handle lot of objects in the workspace:

```
r_list <- list()

for(i in 1:15){
  r_list[[i]] <- mask(New_LULC_2015,New_LULC_2015 != i, maskvalue=1)
}
```